# Cutting a disk with piecewise analytic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, curves, connectedness, plane-curves, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $B \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and assume that the boundary of $B$ consists of finitely many piecewise analytic curves. Suppose $z_0 \in \partial B$ and assume the following:

1. $U(z_0 , r) = \{z : |z - z_0| < r \} \subset \overline{B}$
2. $U(z_0 , r) \cap B$ is disconnected
3. $z_0$ does not lie on any non-analytic part of $\partial B$

Then apparently it is always true that $U(z_0,r) \cap B$ has finitely many connected components.

This seems possible because of the imposed regularity on $\partial B$, but I do not know how to start with proving this.

$\textbf{Edit}$: Added hypothesis previously omitted (namely, $z_0$ does not lie on any non-analytic part of $\partial B$)

$\textbf{Edit 2}$: Moreover, given $\phi : B \rightarrow D$ (here $D = \phi(B)$ is a univalent function on $B$ (holomorphic and one-to-one), and $\partial D$ consists of finitely many piecewise analytic curves, and $\phi(z_0)$ does not lie on any non-analytic part of $\partial D$, why is it possible to extend $\phi$ analytically to a whole open neighbourhood of $z_0$?

$\textbf{Edit 3}$: A piecewise analytic curve is a (continuous) mapping $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, which on each (closed) subinterval $[t_{j-1},t_j]$ of some partition $t_0 = 0 < t_1 < ... < t_n = 1$, is the restriction of a holomorphic function defined on a neighbourhood of the subinterval, moreover we may suppose that this holomorphic function has non-vanishing derivative at each point of the subinterval. So by $z_0$ does not lie on any non analytic part of the boundary, I mean it is not the image of an endpoint of any such subinterval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "analytic", I guess you mean "real analytic" (or else $\partial B$ is discrete). I also guess that you want to prove that $U(z_0,r) \cap B$ has finitely many components up to lowering $r$ (or else, problems could happen far from $z_0$, where $\partial B$ is not analytic).

In this case, as $\partial B$ is analytic around $z_0$ of dimension $1$, then, up to reducing $r$, we can assume that $U(z_0,r) \cap \partial B = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ for some real analytic function $f : U(z_0,r) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. As $U(z_0,r) \subset \overline{B}$, $U(z_0,r) \cap B = U(z_0,r) \cap \left(\overline{B}\backslash\partial B\right)$ (because $B$ is open) $= U(z_0,r)\backslash(U(z_0,r) \cap \partial B) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)$.

$f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a closed analytic subset of $U(z_0,r)$, thus it has a finite number $N$ of irreducible components going through $z_0$. Therefore, up to reducing $r$, its complement $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)$ has less or equal than $2N < +\infty$ connected components.

**Edit :** This last sentence is not true, see the discussion in the comments below.

If $\partial B$ is analytic of dimension $0$ around $z_0$, this point is isolated so $U(z_0,r) \cap B$ has one connected component if $r$ is small enough.

Comment: I've updated my post with what I mean by analytic. But I think it coincides with what you say.

Comment: Actually, I am not so sure your definition and mine coincide. Suppose $z_0=0$ were the center of a 'star' like shape, say something like $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} [-r_i,r_i]$ where $[-r_i,r_i]$ are segments from $-r_i$ to $r_i$ (some complex numbers, and all distinct), and $B$ was equal to the plane minus these segments. How would $U(z_0,r) \cap \partial B = f^{-1}(0)$ for some smooth (analytic as you say) function $f : U(z_0,r) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ as a regular value? If this was the case $U(z_0,r) \cap \partial B$ would necessarily be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: But in my example, that set is clearly not a $1$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it seems your definition and what I meant by analytic do not coincide.

Comment: Notice that $z \in [-r_i,r_i] \Leftrightarrow |z| \leqslant r_i$ and $z\overline{r_i} \in \mathbb{R}$ so $f(z) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \Im(z\overline{r_i})$ works and is real analytic in $x = \Re(z)$ and $y = \Im(z)$. It is not a real manifold around $0$ (unless $n = 1$) because $df(0) = 0$. $0$ is a singular point.

Comment: With your definition, around $t \in ]t_{j - 1},t_j[$ such that $\gamma$ is the restriction of some holomorphic $h$ such that $h'(t) \neq 0$, then by implicit functions theorem, there exists some real valued, real analytic $f$ such that $f(z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \exists s, z = \gamma(s)$ for $z$ close enough to $\gamma(t)$. You definition implies mine. I don't know however, if the converse is true.

Comment: I see! For your second comment, are you saying that since $h(-1,1) = \gamma$, and $h'(0) \neq 0$ (say), then there is an inverse mapping $h^{-1}$ which maps a neighbourhood of $\gamma$ to a neighbourhood of $(-1,1)$ with $\gamma$ sent to $(-1,1)$, and then taking the imaginary part of this map, we get a real analytic map whose preimage at $0$ is $\gamma$, and then for the $n$ possible curves crossing $z_0$, we do the same thing and take products to obtain a real analytic map, with $0$ a singular value, and whose preimage at $0$ is the entire boundary?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your argument where you bring up irreducible components, I know what an irreducible component is in the context of say the Zariski topology, but with respect to the Euclidean topology, aren't irreducible closed sets just points?

Comment: For your first comment, yes $\gamma = h_{|]t - \varepsilon,t + \varepsilon[}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, and yes you can take $f = \Im(h^{-1})$. For the second one, we take the Zariski real analytic topology, where the closed set are the zero locus of families of real analytic functions. It has similarities with the Zariski topology given by polynomials, like being locally Noetherian (but not globally this time !). In other words, around a point in a given Zariski closed, there are a finite number of irreducible components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147130/discussion-between-porridgemathematics-and-cactus).