Pasting lipschitz functions
It is well known that in general, if a function is Lipschitz on compact subsets of $ \mathbb{R^n}$, it does not need to be Lispchitz on the union. However with some additional assumptions, e.g if the union is finite and the union is convex, this is true.
I want to know if this remains true for an annulus $A = \{ r \leq |z| \leq 1 \}$ with $0< r < 1$, that is if there are compact sets $ E_k, k=1,…,n$ such that $\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k = A$, and $f$ is Lipschitz on each $E_k, k=1,…,n $, then is it necessarily true that $f$ is Lispchitz on $A$?
This question really comes down to whether it is possible for any pair of points in $A$, to join them with a path for which the length to Euclidean distance ratio cannot be arbitrarily large.
I think this should be the case because we do not have any slits in the interior of the region, but I wanted to see if anyone knew this to be true or false already.

Could you give some reference as to the results you are citing?

@Jakobian For the result about convexity, the argument goes like this: Join points $z ,z’$ by a straight line segment contained in the union. Find a sequence of points starting at $z$ and ending at $z’$, such that any two consecutive points lie in the same set $E_k$ (this can be done assuming these sets are closed). Then write the difference $|f(z) - f(z’)|$ as a telescoping sum over the sequence, bound it above using Lipschitz in each $E_k$ by a constant times the sum of the lengths of consecutive points, which is a constant times $|z-z’|$

@Jakobian for a concrete reference, see page 2 of “Condenser capacities and symmetrization in geometric function theory” by Vladimir N. Dubinin. In this old post of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734125/lipschitz-functions-theorem-1-4-of-condenser-capacities-and-symmetrization-in-g, you may find a screenshot with the proof given in that reference. It is “Theorem 1.3”.

Your annulus $A$ has the property that for any two points $x, y$ of $A$, there is a curve of length $\le \pi \|x-y\|/2$ in $A$ joining them.  The argument for convex sets can then be applied, up to an extra factor of $\pi/2$.
